# How to update Watch app with updates in core data?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

We support iOS 7, so I am not using a framework.  The app is mostly objective-c, and the watchkit extension mostly in swift.  The AppDelegate manages the Core Data objects.

Our app allows the user to choose a configuration to change what they see.  They can switch to a different configuration.  When they switch, we remove most everything from NSDefaults and we remove the sqlite database and recreate it.  When they switch, its basically starting over.

On the watch side, I have a swift class that has a lazy loaded Singleton of an object that manages the core data objects.  But when the app resets its data, how can we report this out to the watch extension?  I am guessing that I have to reset the managed object context that the extension created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MMWormHole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) to send messages from your iPhone app to your WatchKit extension.  In your WatchKit extension you can set the `stalenessInterval` for your Core Data database to something really short and you will also probably want to refresh your `NSManagedObjects`.